# Is there anyway to get the feature data of .sldprt file without opening it in solidworks?

Tags: api, document, solidworks

I need to get the features of each .sldprt file as the data of other project. But the truth is I have over 50000 .sldprt files, which takes lots of time to open each in solidworks and traverse its features and close it automatically. And I didn't find any solution in api documentation of solidworks in [SOLIDWORKS Document Manager api Help](https://help.solidworks.com/2018/English/api/swdocmgrapi/SolidWorks.Interop.swdocumentmgr%7ESolidWorks.Interop.swdocumentmgr_namespace.html?id=10da8f08d1c140ee963e58fbd930f2c1#Pg0). So is there anyway to get the features and sketches directly without opening the file in solidworks? Such as using the solidworks Document Manager api?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. SolidWorks Document manager can not access any feature or sketch information.

There is no way to go around opening each files in SolidWorks.

But there are some options that could speed up the process. See:
https://cadbooster.com/improve-solidworks-macro-speed-10x/